How would I recreate this creepy pluck sound in serum?
If anyone could help me figure out how to recreate this sound in serum that would be greatly appreciated.
https://www.instagram.com/reel/C8fmdXLxCh1/?igsh=MW1sdTBkcDZncnRi
